# Trouble with Google Analytics/Tag Manager + Meteor

Tags: meteor, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, meteor-galaxy

Having an issue with a Meteor project when it comes to analytics. I've added the gorillastack:iron-router-gtm package to the project, and inside the site everything seems to be working alright. It's when we try to track incoming traffic, we run into issues.

When using UTM codes (source, medium, campaign, etc.) and auto-tagging, tracking parameters are not recorded in Google Analytics.

Google Analytics is bucketing paid search traffic under "organic" or "direct" instead of "cpc".

Is there anything else I need to do with Meteor to fix this issue, or are there setting inside of GA I need to change?

Comment: When you refer to auto-tagging I assume you mean gclids? How are you running UTM and auto-tagging? In Google Analytics under property settings > advanced, have you checked "Allow manual tagging (UTM values) to override auto-tagging (GCLID values) for Adwords and DoubleClick Search integration"? What are the UTM source/medium tags you are using?

Comment: I only have auto-tagging for Google (no UTM overrides).  I only use UTMs for testing source/medium.

For Adwords, Im only using auto-tagging (gclid) but the gclid does not flow into GA. When I click the paid search ads, I see the gclid inside the address bar, but GA real time shows that the source/medium of that click is "google/organic". Should be "google/cpc".

I tried attaching a test UTM onto the URL (/?utm_source=test&utm_medium=test). The custom parameters stay in the address bar, however it doesn't register as "test/test", instead, GA says (direct)/(none)

Comment: Have you linked your Google Analytics account and your Google AdWords, under Admin > Property > AdWords linking ?

Comment: Could you share an example of URL without host name?

Comment: our URLs are /?utm_source=test&utm_campaign=test&utm_medium=test&utm_term=test&utm_content=test and ?gclid=CJ2voNydz9ACFZFefgodQIIJzw